Using a LAPACK function in C from the Accelerate Package on a M1 Mac
I am working on a scientific package in C and would like to incorporate a few LAPACK functions, which I aim to compile on my M1 MacBook running macOS 15.2. I understand that macOS uses Apple's Accelerate framework to provide implementations of BLAS and LAPACK functions. However, the documentation doesn't explicitly detail the use of LAPACK functions within the Accelerate framework. Instead, it mentions the following in this documentation page.

clapack.h is the interface to Apple’s implementation of LAPACK. Documentation of the LAPACK interfaces, including reference implementations, can be found on the web starting from the LAPACK FAQ page at this URL: http://netlib.org/lapack/faq.html

I am having trouble getting the compiler to work with a LAPACK function. I've created a minimal working example, which attempts to compute the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix using LAPACK's zheev function. The project includes a header file, a main.c file with a simple test, and a Makefile. However, when I run make, the compiler complains that clapack.h doesn't exist. Howwver, without the clapack.h file, the compiler throws an error message saying that LAPACKE_zheev does not exist.
Could someone help me fix this minimal working example?

That is not a [mre]. A [mre] for the clapack.h issue is simply a single-line source code file #include "clapack.h". That suffices to demonstrate the compiler does not find the header. A [mre] for the LAPACKE_zheev issue is the two lines #include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h> and void (*foo)(void) = (void (*)(void)) LAPACKE_zheev;. That suffices to demonstrate LAPACKE_zheev is not declared. You should not use external repositories as a [mre].

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with this area of LAPACK, so I cannot tell you what is wrong. The Accelerate framework does declare a zheev_ (and wants ACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK defined) but not LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR. That string does not appear anywhere in the macOS 15.2 SDK. So I might guess you are trying to use features that are not in Apple’s LAPACK implementation. The LAPACK FAQ you link to says it was last updated in 2017.
